# Неправильное отображение элемента из css с использованием bootstrap на телефоне

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

Необходимо для собственных нужд сделать небольшую веб морду. И поверх картинки наложить текст. Для пк версии написал небольшой кусок который накладывает по верх картинки текст но при открытии с телефона получаю текст в следующей строке. Подскажите что нужно дописать. bootstrap пользую первый и последний раз и найти нужную информацию не получается. Прилагаю Кусок кода из css

```
.containerMy {  position: relative;  text-align: left;  color: white;}
.bottom-right {position: absolute;bottom: 5px;right: 5px;}
```

И Кусок кода из html

```
 <div class="containerMy">
          <div class="row-auto">
             <img src="img/top_b.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
             <div class="bottom-right h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold voltage">Bottom Right</div>
           </div>
 </div>
```

На остальные классы по мимо containerMy и botom-right можно не смотреть они скопипизжены и отлично работают.
Так же прилагаю скриншоты

С пк- [image: С пк]

С телефона[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему бы не использовать стандартные стили для вкладок бутстпрапа?

Comment: @teran Ну это навзячивая мысль. Есть обычный стиль для записи по верх картинки ? Если вы подскажете я буду неимоверно счастлив

Comment: тут вопрос не по бутстрапу просто. закешировались мб стили там у вас на мобиле. в инструментах разработчика в браузере эмуляцию включите мобильных и там тренируйтесь. в вместо картинку проще фоном сделать

Comment: @teran Хочу картинку и все. Хочу что бы вот так красиво было ) Просто я не фанат ваших веб разработок это не в продакшен же пойдет а для меня любимого. Хочу что бы так было красиво) Фон каждый дурак сделает )

Comment: у вас  там точка у класса в стилях пропущена. мб на мобиле закэшировался вариант с ошибкой, потом вы поправили, а там не обновляется.

Comment: @teran нет нет я скопировал не правиль. Я прочитал что надо media контент создавать но принцип для чего и как я не пойму